# Error in graph create: requirement failed: The inlets [] and outlets [] must correspond to the inlets [in] and outlets [out]

Tags: scala, typesafe, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I'm using akka streams graphDSL to create a runnable graph. There are no compile-time errors wrt inlet / outlet of the stream components. Runtime throws following error:

Any ideas what should I verify to make it run ?

```
requirement failed: The inlets [] and outlets [] must correspond to the inlets [in] and outlets [out]
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:219)
at akka.stream.Shape.requireSamePortsAs(Shape.scala:168)
at akka.stream.impl.StreamLayout$CompositeModule.replaceShape(StreamLayout.scala:390)
at akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphApply$class.create(GraphApply.scala:18)
at akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL$.create(Graph.scala:813)
at com.flipkart.connekt.busybees.streams.Topology$.bootstrap(Topology.scala:109)
at com.flipkart.connekt.busybees.BusyBeesBoot$.start(BusyBeesBoot.scala:65)
at com.flipkart.connekt.boot.Boot$.delayedEndpoint$com$flipkart$connekt$boot$Boot$1(Boot.scala:39)
at com.flipkart.connekt.boot.Boot$delayedInit$body.apply(Boot.scala:13)
```

The graph structure:

```
source ~> flowRate ~> render ~> platformPartition.in
platformPartition.out(0) ~> formatIOS ~> apnsDispatcher ~> apnsEventCreator ~> merger.in(0)
platformPartition.out(1) ~> formatAndroid ~> httpDispatcher ~> gcmPoolFlow ~> rHandlerGCM ~> merger.in(1)
merger.out ~> evtCreator ~> Sink.ignore
```

Comment: Can you actually post your graph blueprint?

Comment: I've updated the question with graph structure. The source/flow/sink type parameters all match on inlet / outlet.

Comment: The types of `render`, `platformPartition`, `merger` and `evtCreator` could be useful as well.

Comment: I think a broader portion of your code could be helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have an unused inlet or outlet (one of your flows or something isn't connected on all sides). Here are some examples:

This works:

```
val workingFlow =
  Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    val intFlow = b.add(Flow[Int])
    FlowShape(intFlow.in, intFlow.out)
  })
```

The following code produces an error similar to yours, because it has an entire unused flow:

```
val buggyFlow =
  Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    val intFlow = b.add(Flow[Int])
    val unusedFlow = b.add(Flow[Int]) // ERROR: This flow is unused
    FlowShape(intFlow.in, intFlow.out)
  })
```

A slightly more complex example: Here there isn't an entire unused flow, there's just an unused outlet. It produces the same error:

```
val buggyFlow =
  Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
    val intFlow = b.add(Flow[Int])
    val unusedFlow = b.add(Flow[Int]) // ERROR: This flow's outlet isn't used

    broadcast ~> intFlow
    broadcast ~> unusedFlow

    FlowShape(broadcast.in, intFlow.out)
  })
```

Comment: yes, we figured that out long back. The error message is non-intuitive. I should have updated the question. :)
Thanks, though for looking into it.